# Delete a Specific values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an intermediate list in the following format

```
input = [{'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000144', 'Stack': 'Java', 'Code': 2214}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000198', 'Stack ': '.net', 'Code': 1494}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000121', 'Stack': 'Ruby', 'Code': 1112}]
```

I need to delete all the occurrences of 'Code'

```
expected output = [{'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000144', 'Stack': 'Java'}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000198', 'Stack ': '.net'}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000121', 'Stack': 'Ruby'}]
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 4):

This line of code should work:

```
for i in input:
    i.pop("Code")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
dd = [i.pop("Code") for i in input]
print(input)

    [{'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000144', 'Stack': 'Java'}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000198', 'Stack ': '.net'}, {'EmpId': '00030010-0010-0000-0000-000000000121', 'Stack': 'Ruby'}]
```